# POSTGRES unable to connect with container

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances

I tried implementing Postgres with Odoo in Azure through docker compose, but I faced this error when I tried to check Odoo's container logs :

> Database connection failure: connection to server at "db" (127.0.0.1),
> port 5432 failed: Connection refused
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections ?

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
   db:
     image: registryodoo.azurecr.io/samples/postgres:13
     volumes:
       - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
     deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
     expose:
       - 5432
     environment:
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: odoo
       POSTGRES_DB: postgres
       POSTGRES_USER: odoo
       PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

   odoocontainer:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: registryodoo.azurecr.io/samples/odoo:latest
     volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/odoo
      - extra-addons:/mnt/extra-addons
     ports:
       - 8069:8069
     deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
     environment:
       HOST: db
       USER: odoo
       PASSWORD: odoo
volumes:
  data:   
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: odoofileshare
      storage_account_name: odooaccount1
  db:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: odoofileshare
      storage_account_name: odooaccount1

  extra-addons:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: odoofileshare
      storage_account_name: odooaccount1
```

After looking at some answers in related questions I tried with : **expose : - 5432** , **ports : - 5432** and **not writing it** the docker compose I still had the same issue.

Here's a screen of the container logs:

[Azure container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWn5a.png)

Comment: Your database is not available at `127.0.0.1` (that would mean "the same container as your application"). It is available at the hostname `db`.

Comment: That's what I understood from the error, so what should I change ?

Comment: There's nothing obvious to change in your `docker-compose.yaml`. Somewhere there is a way to specify database connection parameteres for Odoo; I'm not familiar with Odoo so I can't offer any suggestions. You'd have to check the docs to see how to do that.